# how to import pymongo in python3 without virtualenv?

Tags: python3

I'm new in python and I am starting a new project with mongodb and python3, but when I import pymongo in my script it give me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

**Please note that I am running this python script from command line, not from a GUI.**

Comment: Did you install `pymongo`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Python's 'batteries included' doesn't mean all Python modules exist on a system.

Open a terminal and install the [pymongo package from Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/3.0.3).  The developers suggest:

> If you have setuptools installed you should be able to do easy_install pymongo to install PyMongo. Otherwise you can download the project source and do python setup.py install to install.

They also continue

> Do not install the “bson” package. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing “easy_install bson” installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo

I add this because if you were to use `sudo apt-get- install python3-pymongo` you would be required to install four additional packages, two of which would be python3-bson and python3-bson-ext.  I have not used `pymongo` so I don't know the implication of that.